Sifting property of Dirac delta function
For a function $f(t)$ of a single variable, I know the following property of the Dirac delta function:
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \delta(t-a) \, dt = f(a).$
But, what if we have a function of two or more variables? Say, we have a function $f(x, t)\in L^1(\mathbb{R^2})$. Then can we have the property:
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x, t) \delta(x-a) \delta(t-b) \, dx \, dt = f(a, b) ?$
Or, do we have something like a "two-dimensional Dirac delta function,”
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x, t) \delta(x-a, t-b) \, dx \, dt = f(a, b) ?$

Note that your first double integral can be written $$\int \delta(t-b) \left( \int f(x,t) \delta(x-a) ,\mathrm{d}x \right) ,\mathrm{d}t  \text{,}$$ which you should recognize does exactly what you want.

Both of these are already valid statements. Where things get more involved is in the context of different coordinate systems, e.g., the Dirac delta function in polar coordinates as discussed here.

@EricTowers sir, in that case: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \delta(t-b) ( \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x, t) \delta(x-a) , dx) , dt$ hence $ =\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-b) f(a, t) dt = f(a, b)$ am I correct sir?

@Semiclassical sir, so you mean there is two dimensional dirac delta function and the property what I write in the post for $\delta(x-a, t-b)$ holds? Moreover, is $\delta(x-a, t-b)=\delta(x-a)\delta(t-b)$?

@EricTowers sir, still I am confused about my last comment. Is it correct? Moreover, how that inner integral reduce to $f(a, t)$? I mean $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x, t) \delta(x-a), dx = f(a, t) ?$ how? Isn't here $f$ is function of two variables and $\delta$ is function of one variable?

That is correct. More generally, the ordinary n-dimensional Dirac delta function is $$\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{a})=\delta(x_1-a_1)\delta(x_2-a_2)\cdots \delta(x_n-a_n)$$

Isn't "shifting" instead of "sifting" ?

@JeanMarie yes, that's a typo. I edited it.

Sifting was correct: see for instance https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SiftingProperty.html. (Sifting means selecting for some particular object. In this case, integrating $\delta(x-a)$ against some function $f(x)$ sifts for the value $f(a)$ and ignores the behavior of $f$ everywhere else.)

Change of variable?

@Semiclassical Thanks for the precision.

The Dirac Delta is NOT a function, and those objects--written as integrals--are NOT integrals.  The Dirac Delta is distribution (a linear functional) that maps functions into numbers.  All of the hand-waving formality with integrals seems to work, but is not rigorous.   If $\phi\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\phi\in C_C^\infty$, then $\langle \delta_{\vec a},\phi\rangle = \phi(\vec a)$, where $\vec a\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is, indeed, a well-defined operation. Consider the 2 Dirac deltas $\delta_a$ and $\delta_b$ where
$$
\int_\mathbf{R} g(t) \delta_a(t) \ dt = \int_\mathbf{R} g(t) \delta(t-a) \ dt= g(a),
$$
and
$$
\int_\mathbf{R} g(t) \delta_b(t) \ dt = g(b),
$$
for any smooth $g$. Then, the operation
$$
\int_\mathbf{R} \delta_a \bigl( \int_\mathbf{R} f(t,s) \delta_b(t) \ dt \bigr) \ ds
$$
is well-defined and equals to $f(a,b)$ for any smooth $f$ on $\mathbf{R^2}$. The "function"  $\delta_a \otimes \delta_b$ is called the tensor-product of $\delta_a$ and $\delta_b$. In other words, the tensor-product operation $(g_1 \otimes g_2) (x,t) = g_1(t)g_2(x)$ for two functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ can also be performed for the dirac delta function.
